# Proving Composition Law for Maybe Applicative

Tags: haskell, applicative

So, I wanted to manually prove the Composition law for Maybe applicative which is:

```
u <*> (v <*> w) = pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w
```

I used these steps to prove it:

```
u <*> (v <*> w)          [Left hand side of the law]
  = (Just f) <*> (v <*> w)  [Assume u ~ Just f]
  = fmap f (v <*> w)
  = fmap f (Just g <*> w)   [Assume v ~ Just g]
  = fmap f (fmap g w)
  = fmap (f . g) w

pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w  [Right hand side of the law]
  = Just (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w
  = fmap (.) u <*> v <*> w
  = fmap (.) (Just f) <*> v <*> w  [Replacing u with Just f]
  = Just (f .) <*> v <*> w
  = Just (f .) <*> Just g <*> w    [Replacing v with Just g]
  = fmap (f .) (Just g) <*> w
  = Just (f . g) <*> w
  = fmap (f . g) w
```

Is proving like this correct? What really concerns me is that I assume `u` and `v` for some functions embedded in `Just` data constructor to proceed with my proof. Is that acceptable? Is there any better way to prove this?

Comment: Sure it's correct to argue by cases.  But you need to also check the `Nothing` case.  And maybe the bottom case if you care about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Applicative functor expressions are just function applications in the context of some functor. Hence:

```
pure f <*> pure a <*> pure b <*> pure c

-- is the same as:

pure (f a b c)
```

We want to prove that:

```
pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w == u <*> (v <*> w)
```

Consider:

```
u = pure f
v = pure g
w = pure x
```

Therefore, the left hand side is:

```
pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w

pure (.) <*> pure f <*> pure g <*> pure x

pure ((.) f g x)

pure ((f . g) x)

pure (f (g x))

pure f <*> pure (g x)

pure f <*> (pure g <*> pure x)

u <*> (v <*> w)
```

For `Maybe` we know that `pure = Just`. Hence if `u`, `v` and `w` are `Just` values then we know that the composition law holds.

However, what if any one of them is `Nothing`? We know that:

```
Nothing <*> _ = Nothing
_ <*> Nothing = Nothing
```

Hence if any one of them is `Nothing` then the entire expression becomes `Nothing` (except in the second case if the first argument is `undefined`) and since `Nothing == Nothing` the law still holds.

Finally, what about `undefined` (a.k.a. bottom) values? We know that:

```
(Just f) <*> (Just x) = Just (f x)
```

Hence the following expressions will make the program halt:

```
(Just f) <*> undefined
undefined <*> (Just x)
undefined <*> Nothing
```

However the following expression will result in `Nothing`:

```
Nothing <*> undefined
```

In either case the composition law still holds.

Comment: According to the instance definition, `Nothing <*> _ = Nothing`. But how do you conclude that `_ <*> Nothing = Nothing` ?

Comment: We know that `(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. Hence if the second parameter was `Nothing` then we have 3 cases: 1) `Nothing <*> Nothing` which is `Nothing`. 2) `Just f <*> Nothing` 3) `undefined <*> Nothing`. The second case evaluates to `Nothing` because there's no way to get a value of type `a` from `Nothing` and apply it to `f (a -> b)` to get a value of type `f b`. The only logical solution is to return `Nothing`. In the third case if we try to evaluate the first argument (i.e. `undefined`) then the program would halt which is wrong. Correct: `_ <*> Nothing = Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks, what does the bottom case has to do here ? You have shown that bottom cases at some situations will make the program halt, so how does that help in proving the laws ?

Comment: Also, at the end of the answer you have written that `undefined <*> Nothing` will result in `Nothing` which is not the case (which you have also mentioned in the previous comment in this thread.)

Comment: Also bottom is not about halting.  In fact an infinite loop is a prominent form of bottom.

Comment: I edited my answer explaining why the implementation differs from what is expected. Granted that `undefined <*> Nothing` makes the program halt instead of returning `Nothing`. However that should not be the case. This is a problem caused because `Applicative` is not yet a superclass of `Monad`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I know that bottom is not about halting. However in the case of a pattern match, it will make the program halt. Trying to evaluate a bottom value (even a little) will make the program halt. In the case of an infinite loop the bottom type represents an absence of data. However the program doesn't halt because you never evaluate a bottom value.

Comment: @AaditMShah There is in ordinary Haskell (without unsafe functions that don't preserve the common semantics of bottom anyhow) no way to define a non-constant function such that both `Nothing <*> undefined` and `undefined <*> Nothing` give `Nothing`. Whether it is defined through `Monad`, `Applicative` or directly makes no difference.

Comment: @Sibi If the program halts then you cannot disprove the law. Hence by negative hypotheses you conclude that the law is true. It's an edge case.

Comment: @AaditMShah The idea that an infinite loop is not a value in Haskell is a non-standard one, which I've seen argued before, and which you may hold, but which I and I think most Haskellers will not agree with.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Makes sense. You would either need to evaluate the first or the second argument. If either of them are `undefined` then you would an error.

Comment: I never said that an infinite loop is not a value. It is a value. It has a type. You can restrict it to any type beside bottom. However the expression will never bottom out.

Comment: @AaditMShah Ah, sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: @AaditMShah How is that related to the Applicative-Monad superclass proposal?

Comment: @DavidYoung I stand corrected. It isn't. Hence I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The rules that are generated by the definition of Maybe are

```
x :: a
---------------
Just x :: Maybe a
```

and

```
a type
-----------------
Nothing :: Maybe a
```

Along with

```
a type
------------------
bottom :: a
```

If these are the only rules which result in `Maybe A` then we can always invert them (run from bottom to top) in proofs so long as we're exhaustive. This is argument by case examination of a value of type `Maybe A`.

You did two cases analyses, but weren't exhaustive. It might be that `u` or `v` are actually `Nothing` or bottom.

Answer (score 3):

A useful tool to learn when proving stuff about Haskell code is Agda:
Here is a short proof stating what you want to prove:

```
data Maybe (A : Set) : Set where
  Just : (a : A) -> Maybe A
  Nothing : Maybe A

_<*>_ : {A B : Set} -> Maybe (A -> B) -> Maybe A -> Maybe B
Just f <*> Just a = Just (f a)
Just f <*> Nothing = Nothing
Nothing <*> a = Nothing

pure : {A : Set} -> (a : A) -> Maybe A
pure a = Just a

data _≡_ {A : Set} (x : A) : A → Set where
  refl : x ≡ x

_∘_ : {A B C : Set} ->
      (B -> C) -> (A -> B) -> A -> C
_∘_ f g = λ z → f (g z)

maybeAppComp : {A B C : Set} -> (u : Maybe (B -> A)) -> (v : Maybe (C -> B)) -> (w : Maybe C)
            -> (u <*> (v <*> w)) ≡ (((pure _∘_ <*> u) <*> v) <*> w)
maybeAppComp (Just f) (Just g) (Just w) = refl
maybeAppComp (Just f) (Just g) Nothing = refl
maybeAppComp (Just f) Nothing (Just w) = refl
maybeAppComp (Just f) Nothing Nothing = refl
maybeAppComp Nothing (Just g) (Just w) = refl
maybeAppComp Nothing (Just a) Nothing = refl
maybeAppComp Nothing Nothing (Just w) = refl
maybeAppComp Nothing Nothing Nothing = refl
```

This illustrates a couple of points others have pointed out:

- Which definitions you use are important for the proof, and should be made explicit. In my case I did not want to use Agda's libraries.
- Case analysis is key to making these kinds of proofs.
- In fact, the proof becomes trivial once case analysis is done. The Agda compire/proof system is able to unify the proof for you.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the Agda approach although I cannot make any sense of it. :) Just curious to know, if the function `maybeAppComp`is auto-generated or you explicitly write the 8 cases ?

Comment: Agda has an interactive mode that works in tandem with you.
At first the code looks like this:

    `maybeAppComp u v w = ?`

Then you put the cursor on the question mark enters the variable `u`, and presses `C-c C-c` which does the case analysis for you. If this is done for all variables you end up with:

`maybeAppComp (Just f) (Just g) (Just w) = ?`

And so on. Then you put the cursor on the question mark, and press `C-c C-a`, which instructs Agda to find a proof. It finds the trivial proof of `refl`.

The only thing you explicitly have to write is the type of the proof.

Comment: The type of the proof is quite interesting. It says it can take any values of u v w and construct the desired proof

Comment: Thanks, looks very interesting. Will try to learn this tool. :)

Answer (score 2):

You translated the use of `(<*>)` through `fmap`. The other answers also do some pattern matching.

Usually you need to open the definition of the functions to reason about them, not just assume what they do. (You assume `(pure f) <*> x` is the same as `fmap f x`)

For example, `(<*>)` is defined as `ap` for `Maybe` in `Control.Applicative` (or can be proven to be equivalent to it for any `Monad`, even if you redefine it), and `ap` is borrowed from `Monad`, which is defined as `liftM2 id`, and `liftM2` is defined like so:

```
liftM2 f m1 m2 = do
    x <- m1
    y <- m2
    return $ f x y
```

So, reduce both left- and right-hand sides to see they are equivalent:

```
u <*> (v <*> w) = liftM2 id u (liftM2 id v w)
 = do
     u1 <- u
     v1 <- do
             v1 <- v
             w1 <- w
             return $ id v1 w1
     return $ id u1 v1
 = do
     u1 <- u
     v1 <- do
             v1 <- v
             w1 <- w
             return $ v1 w1
     return $ u1 v1
 -- associativity law: (see [1])
 = do
     u1 <- u
     v1 <- v
     w1 <- w
     x <- return $ v1 w1
     return $ u1 x
 -- right identity: x' <- return x; f x'  == f x
 = do
     u1 <- u
     v1 <- v
     w1 <- w
     return $ u1 $ v1 w1
```

Now, the right-hand side:

```
pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w
 = liftM2 id (liftM2 id (liftM2 id (pure (.)) u) v) w
 = do
     g <- do
            f <- do
                   p <- pure (.)
                   u1 <- u
                   return $ id p u1
            v1 <- v
            return $ id f v1
     w1 <- w
     return $ id g w1
 = do
     g <- do
            f <- do
                   p <- return (.)
                   u1 <- u
                   return $ p u1
            v1 <- v
            return $ f v1
     w1 <- w
     return $ g w1
 -- associativity law:
 = do
    p <- return (.)
    u1 <- u
    f <- return $ p u1
    v1 <- v
    g <- return $ f v1
    w1 <- w
    return $ g w1
 -- right identity: x' <- return x; f x'  ==  f x
 = do
    u1 <- u
    v1 <- v
    w1 <- w
    return $ ((.) u1 v1) w1
 -- (f . g) x  == f (g x)
 = do
    u1 <- u
    v1 <- v
    w1 <- w
    return $ u1 $ v1 w1
```

That's it.

[1] http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws

Comment: +1 This is nice, yet using the Monad laws instead of the Applicative ones makes the exercise a bit different, I think.

Comment: @chi well, what do you do if `(<*>)` is defined through `ap`? I don't see it overloaded through `fmap` for `Maybe`, am I missing something? That's the reason I find the solutions proposed here not strictly correct.

Comment: `<*>` is not defined as `ap`: rather, they must be equal when the applicative functor happens to be a monad as well. In the general case, the applicative functor is not a monad, yet `pure` and `<*>` exist and satisfy the [applicative laws](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_Functors).

Comment: In the specific case of the Maybe functor, though, you are right in that it IS defined as `ap`. Yet using the monad laws to prove the applicative ones feels "wrong" in the sense that one is using a more powerful general law to prove a more specific one. It would feel nicer if `<*>` was defined more explicitly without resorting to `ap`. Alternatively, one can take the definition of `ap`, avoid assuming it satisfies the monad laws, and prove the applicative laws for Maybe using such definition.

Comment: @chi sure. My main point I still would like to emphasize that one needs to look at the definition. It is possible to define `(<*>)` differently for `Maybe` (for example, using pattern-matching), but then the topic starter should have specified it - and it would become obvious, for example, that the `Nothing` case should be covered, and what to do with the `undefined` case.