# How to test the Functor laws with the checkers library

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

How do I use the [checkers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers) library to test the Functor laws of a simple Parser?

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Checkers
import Test.QuickCheck.Classes
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

type Index = Int

newtype Parser a = Parser (BS.ByteString -> Index -> (a, Index))

runParser :: Parser a -> BS.ByteString -> Index -> (a, Index)
runParser (Parser p) = p

instance Functor Parser where
    f `fmap` p = Parser $  \bs i -> 
      let (a, ix) = runParser p bs i
      in (f a, ix)
```

I think I have to use the *functor* function from [Test.QuickCheck.Classes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.4.9.5/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Classes.html)

The type is:

```
functor :: forall m a b c. (Functor m, Arbitrary a, Arbitrary b, Arbitrary c, 
           CoArbitrary a, CoArbitrary b, Show (m a), Arbitrary (m a), EqProp (m a), EqProp (m c)) 
           => m (a, b, c) -> TestBatch
```

Now *m* should probably be my Functor *Parser*, so I need something like

```
main :: IO ()
main = = quickBatch (functor (Parser (a, b, c))
```

But what do I use for `(a, b, c)` ?

Note: I know a quick QuickTest test is not a proof and I have read the discussion in 
[How do I test this applicative instance with checkers? (No instance for CoArbitrary (Validation e0 [Char]))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36009335/how-do-i-test-this-applicative-instance-with-checkers-no-instance-for-coarbitr) .
However if the quick test fails, I know that my Functor instance is broken...

**Edit**

I made a little progress: I can write

```
main :: IO ()
main = quickBatch $ functor (undefined :: Parser (Int, String, Char))
```

This gives an error: *No instance for (Show (Parser Int))*

In the type signature of *functor*, there is no *Read* instance mentioned,
so I can write

```
instance Show (Parser a) where
   show (Parser a) = "Parsers cannot be printed"
```

This the gives a new error:

```
• No instance for (Arbitrary (Parser Int))
    arising from a use of ‘functor’
• In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
```

and I guess this is a tougher problem...

Comment: free theorem says you will just need to check identity law. is that possible for you to generate parser instance and see if identity law holds? i don't really know checkers, though.

Comment: The implementation of `functor` ensures that the *values* of `a`, `b`, and `c` are irrelevant; only their *types* matter (perhaps it should take a proxy argument instead, but this is likely more convenient in most cases). But I'm not sure how you're supposed to choose those types.