# How do I create an applicative instance for ziplist?

Tags: list, haskell, applicative

I want to implement an instance of Applicative for my custom list.

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Checkers
import Test.QuickCheck.Classes


data List a =
  Nil
  | Cons a (List a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Eq a => EqProp (List a) where (=-=) = eq

instance Functor List where
  fmap _ Nil = Nil
  fmap f (Cons a Nil) = (Cons (f a) Nil)
  fmap f (Cons a as) = (Cons (f a) (fmap f as))

main = do
  let trigger = undefined :: List (Int, String, Int)
  quickBatch $ applicative trigger


instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (List a)  where
  arbitrary = sized go
    where go 0 = pure Nil
          go n = do
            xs <- go (n - 1)
            x  <- arbitrary
            return (Cons x xs)

instance Applicative List where
  pure x = (Cons x Nil)
  Nil <*> _ = Nil
  _ <*> Nil = Nil
 (Cons f fs) <*> (Cons a as) = (Cons (f a) (fs <*> as))
```

This gives the following bugs:

```
λ> main
applicative:
  identity:     *** Failed! Falsifiable (after 3 tests): 
Cons 0 (Cons (-1) Nil)
  composition:  *** Failed! Falsifiable (after 3 tests): 
Cons <function> (Cons <function> Nil)
Cons <function> (Cons <function> Nil)
Cons 1 (Cons (-2) Nil)
  homomorphism: +++ OK, passed 500 tests.
  interchange:  +++ OK, passed 500 tests.
  functor:      *** Failed! Falsifiable (after 3 tests): 
<function>
Cons (-2) (Cons (-1) Nil)
```

First is the id law is failing:

```
λ> Cons id Nil <*> Cons 0 (Cons (-1) Nil)
Cons 0 Nil
```

How do I fix this? pure takes an `a` not a `List a` so I do not see how to match on List and preserve the nested list structure.

The composition law also fails which is not strange:

```
λ> (Cons "b" Nil) <*> (Cons "c" Nil)

<interactive>:295:7:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char] -> b’
                with actual type ‘[Char]’
    Relevant bindings include
      it :: List b (bound at <interactive>:295:1)
    In the first argument of ‘Cons’, namely ‘"b"’
    In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘(Cons "b" Nil)’
    In the expression: (Cons "b" Nil) <*> (Cons "c" Nil)
```

Edit: since I got great answers implementing applicative for ziplists, I have changed the question to be about ziplists.

Comment: FYI, your `fmap` definition has an extra case it doesn't need. Can you figure out which?

Comment: the Composition law for Applicatives is [`u <*> (v <*> w) = pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129197/proving-composition-law-for-maybe-applicative).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your `ZipList`-like approach we expect the following left-identity to hold:

```
pure id <*> someList = someList
```

For this, `pure` cannot return a single-element list, since this will stop immediately:

```
(Cons id Nil) <*> Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)
  = Cons (id 1) (Nil <*> Cons 2 Nil)
  = Cons 1 Nil
```

Which isn't the expected result for the left-identity. If `pure` cannot return only a single element list, how many should it return? The answer is: infinite:

```
repeatList :: a -> List a
repeatList x = let c = Cons x c in c
```

Why did I call this the `ZipList` approach? Because it's the same behaviour as in [`Control.Applicative.ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList), which can be motivated with `zipWith`:

```
zipWithList :: (a -> b -> c) -> List a -> List b -> List c
zipWithList f (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = Cons (f x y) (zipWithList f xs ys)
zipWithList _ _           _           = Nil
```

Now your instance is

```
instance Applicative List where
  pure  = repeatList
  (<*>) = zipWithList ($)
```

**However**, `checkers` cannot check this instance either due to your `EqProb` instance, since `pure f <*> pure x == pure (f x)` (homomorphism) results in a check on infinite lists. You can provide an alternative one, though. For example, you can take an arbitrary number of elements and compare them:

```
prop_sameList :: Eq a => (Int, Int) -> List a -> List a -> Property
prop_sameList bounds xs ys = forAll (choose bounds) $ \n -> 
  takeList n xs `eq` takeList n ys

takeList :: Int -> List a -> List a
takeList _ Nil = Nil
takeList n (Cons x xs)
 | n <= 0    = Nil
 | otherwise = Cons x (takeList (n - 1) xs)
```

Then, if you want to compare at least `1000` and at most `10000` elements, you can use:

```
instance Eq a => EqProb (List a) where
  (=-=) = prop_sameList (1000, 10000)
```

After all, we're just trying to find a list where our property does *not* hold.

Comment: Actually, `checkers` should be able to test this instance.  QuickCheck is a tool for finding **counterexamples** to properties, not for proving universal propositions. It cannot prove that two infinite lists are equal, but it can test for **equal prefixes** to some depth, and report on counterexamples if any are found. This is why `checkers` uses its own [`EqProp` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.4.4/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Checkers.html#t:EqProp) ("Types of values that can be tested for equality, perhaps through random sampling") instead of the standard `Eq` class.

Comment: Getting this error on second f in middle zWL definition line: ```chap18/List.hs:34:47: Couldn't match expected type ‘b -> c’ with actual type ‘b’ …
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            zipWithList :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b -> List c
          at /Users/ebs/code/haskell/book/chap18/List.hs:33:16
```

Comment: @TheUnfunCat oh, zWL's signature is wrong, first type should be (a -> b -> c).

Comment: I was retrying the exercise above again (haskellbook.com) and I do not think it was intended to be a ziplist, only a regular list. You were probably led astray by my bad attempt. Could you extend your answer with a short implementation of applicative for the regular list? It is what the q asks, but I could also change question to "applicative for ziplist" and then ask a new question with applicative for list.

Comment: Wait, this is the applicative instance for the regular list: `instance Applicative [] where
  pure x    = [x]
  gs <*> xs = [ g x | g <- gs, x <- xs ]`. Isn't that what I am doing above in my question with `(Cons f fs) <*> (Cons a as) = (Cons (f a) (fs <*> as))`?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat To be honest, I would change your question slightly so that it actually asks for the `ZipList` and then open a new one. You can never be sure whether the answer's author is still active on StackOverflow\*. That being said: no. It's not the same. How often is `g` applied in the `Applicative []` instance, how often is `f` applied in yours? \*Oh wow, I'm way to tired, you just proposed that. Whoops.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat no, it' not. what you're doing is `gs <*> xs = [ g x | g <- gs | x <- xs ] == [ g x | (g,x) <- zip gs xs ]`. Regular list comprehensions define *nested* loops: `[ g x | g <- gs, x <- xs ] == {for g in gs: {for x in xs: emit (g x)}} == concat (map (\g-> map g xs) gs)` (or something).

Comment: ... i.e. for your data type it's `(Cons f fs) <*> as = append (fmap f as) (fs <*> as) where append Nil ys = ys; append (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x (append xs ys)`.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment to Zeta's much more deserving answer, you need a second change to get this test to run:

```
-- | Test lists for equality (fallibly) by comparing finite prefixes
--  of them.  I've arbitrarily chosen a depth of 1,000. There may be 
-- better ideas than that.
instance Eq a => EqProp (List a) where
    xs =-= ys = takeList 1000 xs `eq` takeList 1000 ys

-- | Take a prefix of up to @n@ elements from a 'List'.
takeList :: Int -> List a -> List a
takeList _ Nil = Nil
takeList n (Cons a as)
    | n > 0 = Cons a (takeList (n-1) as)
    | otherwise = Nil
```

With Zeta's changes and this one, your test suite passes:

```
applicative:
  identity:     +++ OK, passed 500 tests.
  composition:  +++ OK, passed 500 tests.
  homomorphism: +++ OK, passed 500 tests.
  interchange:  +++ OK, passed 500 tests.
  functor:      +++ OK, passed 500 tests.
```

The key insight to get here is that QuickCheck is, fundamentally, a tool for finding **counterexamples** to properties.  QuickCheck generally cannot prove that a property holds for all possible inputs, because the domain may be infinite.  That's the reason why there's an [`EqProp` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.4.4/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Checkers.html#t:EqProp) in `checkers` ("Types of values that can be tested for equality, perhaps through random sampling")—so that we may implement techniques for searching for counterexamples for types and tests that don't admit of simple equality comparisons.